# Filter Rows in Join Table - Many to Many in Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I'm trying to implement a soft delete across my entire platform. Each table has a `deleted_on` column that will be used to filter out deleted rows.

This includes the join table that I have that's between my files and users. I haven't had any luck finding anything that could help. Right now my classes look like this

```
@Entity
public class File {

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "file_user",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "file_id", referencedColumnName = "file_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    )
    private List<User> users;

    // Constructor and other fields
}
```

User class:

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "users")
    private List<FileData> files = new ArrayList<>();

    // Constructor and other fields
}
```

If it's possible I would like to be able to run the following code without filtering it in the business code

```
File file = fileRepository.findOne(fileKey);
file.getUsers().remove(user);
fileRepository.save(file);
```

Answer (score 4):

if you are `Hibernate` as your JPA provider, then you can use the `@Where` annotation

```
@Entity
@Where(clause="deleted_on=1")
public class User {

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "users")
    private List<FileData> files = new ArrayList<>();

    // Constructor and other fields
}
```

this will apply the where clause on all your queries with User Class

*Additional Note:*

you need to specify the @where clause again in all your relationships

```
@ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "file_user",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "file_id", referencedColumnName = "file_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    )
@Where(clause="deleted_on=1")
    private List<User> users;
```

Comment: @autin the `@Where` annotation should be `@WhereJoinTable` instead